# mysql result check while mysql select is inside for loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

Evening,

I have piece of code:

```
for ($i=0; $i < $c; $i++){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ad_id,title FROM `ads` WHERE `ad_id`='".$new[$i]."' LIMIT 10");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if(($c > 3) && ($i < 2)){
                echo '
                <div class="pins best">
                     <div class="holder">

                         '.$row['title'].'
                     </div>
                </div>';
            } else {
                echo '
                <div class="pins">
                     <div class="holder">
                         '.$row['title'].'
                     </div>
                </div>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "No results";
    }
}
```

Now what i am doing is checking each `id` which i have in `$new` array with `id` coresponding in `db`.

What I can not accomplish is to output some message to user if there are no results matching `db` records. I tried to write after an `if` statement, `else` statement, but it doesn't work because this `db` selection is in `for` loop.

Any suggestions?

**EDITED: I added the else statement to my code,because everyone suggesting what I already tried, and that's where the problem is.**

Comment: Do not use mysql_query. It will be removed in the future: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Yes, I know that,Daniel. The reason why I am using, because I don't really know really good mysqli yet and this is like a prototype of my project, after I will have all piecies working together I will make it with mysqli

Comment: You should follow some tutorials on PDO. Why waste your energy on the old school. It will take some effort, but after that you'll love it. I would suggest catching the `id` that fails in another array. See below.

Comment: I did some project with PDO and to be honest I hated it, it is way too confusing for me, but I will have to learn it anyway, but for me doing with mysql is like making a sketch..After all stuff works, I simply conwert all the code to mysqli

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
...
}
else {
    //message here 
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: yes its an answer, phrased as a question, thx for ur input tho

Comment: Yes I did,I mentioned it in my question as well

Comment: well you haven't been very clear - "does not work" , does not tell us anything

Answer (score 0):

Your code is 99% there:

```
    for ($i=0; $i < $c; $i++) { 
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT ad_id,title FROM `ads` WHERE `ad_id`='".$new[$i]."' LIMIT 10");
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                if(($c > 3) && ($i < 2)){
                     echo '
                            <div class="pins best">
                                 <div class="holder">

                                     '.$row['title'].'
                                 </div>
                            </div>
                        ';
                } else {
                echo '
                        <div class="pins">
                             <div class="holder">

                                 '.$row['title'].'
                             </div>
                        </div>

                    ';

                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'No results found';
        }

    }
```

The while loop never gets executed at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect the ones that fail in an array`$failedId`, after that you can do something with that collection and iterate your `$new` array to generate the feedback.

```
$failedId = array();

for ($i=0; $i < $c; $i++){
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ad_id,title FROM `ads` WHERE `ad_id`='".$new[$i]."' LIMIT 10");
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if(($c > 3) && ($i < 2)){
                echo '
                <div class="pins best">
                     <div class="holder">

                         '.$row['title'].'
                     </div>
                </div>';
            } else {
                echo '
                <div class="pins">
                     <div class="holder">
                         '.$row['title'].'
                     </div>
                </div>';
            }
        }
    } else {
        $failedId[] = $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I sorted out myself. If someone is interesting, after I make an array with id's which are matching the search word in database, I simply check if array or result is empty (that means no match was found) and then print out the message and this check is done before given code above. **Thanks for those who took their time to help me.**